# Raspberry PI 3 Model B+ resetting after every reboot

Tags: camera, keyboard, noobs, raspi-config, reset

My RPi 3 resets itself after every reboot. All my settings, customizations etc are lost. Keyboard layouts, date/time setting, setting in the `sudo raspi-config` (camera setting etc), desktop customizations, everything is lost every time I reboot my Pi.

I am using a 16GB Sandisk memory card which came with my Pi, NOOBS preloaded.

All the data however, which I store on the Pi, web browser cookies etc are left unharmed. I complied OpenCV libraries on my Pi sometime ago and they are also there.

What is this problem and how do I fix it **WITHOUT HAVING TO FORMAT MY EXISTING CARD OR BUYING A NEW ONE.**

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure your file system can successfully be mounted as read/write (instead of read-only) during boot? There are multiple possibilities for this step to fail (i.e. bad file system, bad card, write-protect switch engaged). Check your log files. What steps have you tried?

Comment: @sekdiy Actually I haven't done much... There's no write protect switch in my sd card. (its micro sd).  A bad card is the last thing I wanna hear. What tests can I actually do?

Comment: I'd look into the log files next, see if the file system was mounted correctly. Also, a `fsck` run can't hurt. Additionally, it's possible that something went wrong during pre-loading of the card. It's not that hard to do yourself, really (seeing that you probably didn't change anything anyway).

Comment: @sekdiy well I'll do em and post back the results

Comment: When you say you are using NOOBS, do you mean you are using it with Raspbian, or some other OS (since it is not really an OS in itself except in a specialized sense)?

Comment: @goldilocks yes I am using Raspbian... Did NOOBS comes with other OSs as well? I didn't think it did that's why I didn't mention this in the question.

Comment: It doesn't come with them as far as I know, but it is possible that you were using something else and there's nothing in the question which would rule this out.  Ubuntu snappy, e.g., is read-only and it may be possible to install software there which is not configured to deal with that appropriately.

Comment: I've closed the previous question as a duplicate of this one, hopefully other people will catch onto that and give you another chance since it has been almost a month.  However, don't keep re-asking beyond this point.  If you don't get a solution here obviously  *you will have to "format your existing card or try a new one"*.

Comment: @goldilocks dead end then??

Comment: @YaddyVirus This can remain open; the closed one links to it, so if anyone at some point has a suggestion, etc., they're free to answer.  I just think it's unlikely, so it's up to you how long you want to wait before re-formatting that card or splurging for a new one to try with a fresh image.  Mistakes happen.   Maybe you made one, maybe it's just happenstance.  The former you can usually learn from, the latter maybe so and maybe not but either way you may have to accept it.

Comment: @goldilocks hard luck then... I am going to format it

Comment: @YaddyVirus have you checked your sd card for a physical read only access button.

Comment: @MohammadAli yes I did... It doesn't have one. However the adapter it came with has one

Comment: What do you see when you load up config.txt when you connect your sd card to a PC?

Comment: Most of the times its empty, sometimes it not @MohammadAli

Comment: Your going to need to elaborate on that, because when it's not empty that means that your settings have been saved, so when is it empty and when is it not?

Comment: I'd say its empty in 8 out of 10 reboots

Comment: @MohammadAli But the changes in my config.txt stay. I mean I've made some display changes and they stay everytime I reboot my pi

Comment: @YaddyVirus you should be able to make any modifications that you wanted to do from `raspi-config` in the config.txt file

Comment: @MohammadAli how?? But still what about my other settings? Time/ keyboard layout, desktop customizations?

Comment: @YaddyVirus try using this command to edit your keyboard settings `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`

Comment: Nah I can keep the settings, they're gone when the pi reboots